# Dart code instrumentation possible?

Tags: dart

I know that Dart's VM is a "language VM" as opposed to a bytecode VM. Is there a way to do the equivalent of bytecode instrumentation on Dart code?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember there was a similar question somewhere recently (Dart Google groups) in relation to profiling and the answer was no.
You can do code generation like Angular/DI does it to replace dynamic injection with static injection (Polymer transformer does something along this lines). 
But that is only possible before the program is started.